# Rails 7 ActionController::RoutingError stimulus controller with outdated digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, import-maps

**Edit:** A simpler example than my original question, my CSS is experiencing the same caching issue. Using the `dartsass-rails` gem, with the `bin/rails dartsass:watch` in development. Default configuration. Changes to my SASS files throw an error because Rails goes looking for an outdated digest.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-01d05ee418a658bda88e5c4b0f5b5b1e7610df787a559e2151838d567ecfe62d.css"):
```

(Original post follows)

I have a stimulus controller `app/javascript/editor/section.js`. I am using a default Rails 7 configuration, using import maps along with Stimulus. I am running Puma locally in the `development` environment, with no changes to default configuration.

Whenever I make changes to my stimulus controller, the web server does not pick up the changes, and continues looking for the outdated controller digest, throwing 404 errors.

Javascript console errors like this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/editor/section-ca5da14b07bf02053399e5391d999b5870acc0d8783bb5d7844ce5a22f2278da.js 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Failed to register controller: editor (controllers/editor_controller) Error: 404 Not Found 
http://localhost:3000/assets/editor/section-ca5da14b07bf02053399e5391d999b5870acc0d8783bb5d7844ce5a22f2278da.js 
imported from http://localhost:3000/assets/controllers/editor_controller-0…31577c25719d88e9ca691b7736994a3335959f5513834f370414835d3.js
```

Puma console also complains:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/editor/section-ca5da14b07bf02053399e5391d999b5870acc0d8783bb5d7844ce5a22f2278da.js"):
```

The reason for the error is known: the file has changed and been rebuilt, so the digest has changed. I just don't understand why the updated file isn't being picked up right away.

I have observed the behavior in Firefox and Chrome, with the `Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)` option enabled for both. Restarting the Puma web server will also correct the issue.